# How to ensure at least one of the Fields is not blank in Serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am creating an API to update some of my model's fields, I want the fields to be optional.
At the same time, I don't want to accept an empty request (a request with empty body)

I tried with "required=False" but this will allow empty requests.

```py
class NotificationsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    notify_add_friend = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    notify_added_to_group = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Is there anyway to define a validator for the whole serializer or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [object-level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation):

for specific fields:

```py
class NotificationsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    notify_add_friend = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    notify_added_to_group = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)

    def validate(self, data):
        if 'notify_add_friend' not in data and 'notify_added_to_group' not in data:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Must include either notify_add_friend or notify_added_to_group")
        return data
```

for whole serializer:

```py
class NotificationsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    notify_add_friend = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    notify_added_to_group = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)

    def validate(self, data):
        if not data:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Must include at least one field")
        return data
```